# Move two X-RAIDed disks to ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, software-raid, readynas

I have an old NAS (Netgear ReadyNAS Duo) that are X-RAID (Expandable RAID) that I need to move on to a new Ubuntu 12.04 Server.

Assuming that this is software raided, does anyone know where I can find the drivers to for Ubuntu so that they will continue to work raided?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd never heard of X-Raid before, but I'm positing you can't based on [this](http://www.readynas.com/?p=214) article and [this one](http://www.readynas.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=55113) to.